# How can convert text data to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, currency

I have text data which can obtain from the link

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&interval=5min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

I need to put it in array (python) on this form

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Request the data using `requests`

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query'
params = {
    'function': 'FX_INTRADAY',
    'from_symbol': 'EUR',
    'to_symbol': 'USD',
    'interval': '5min',
    'outputsize': 'full',
    'apikey': 'demo'
}

res = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = res.json()
```

See more information about `requests` at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/.

### 2. Parsing the data

At this point the data is in the following form:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "FX Intraday (5min) Time Series",
        "2. From Symbol": "EUR",
        "3. To Symbol": "USD",
        "4. Last Refreshed": "2020-12-25 08:10:00",
        "5. Interval": "5min",
        "6. Output Size": "Full size",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    },
    "Time Series FX (5min)": {
        "2020-12-25 08:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2187",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

We will only focus on the inner data under "Time Series FX (5min)", which we can easily place into a `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Get '5min' dynamically, so you can use different intervals easily
key = f'Time Series FX ({params["interval"]})'

# orient='index' makes the timestamps the rows and not the columns
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data[key], orient='index')

# Rename the columns to remove opening numbers
df.rename(columns=lambda c: c[3:], inplace=True)
```

Now `df` will have the desired data! You can find more information about `pandas` at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simply reading the text into a `dictionary` in python and creating a `dataframe` out of it:

```
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "FX Intraday (5min) Time Series",
        "2. From Symbol": "EUR",
        "3. To Symbol": "USD",
        "4. Last Refreshed": "2020-12-25 08:10:00",
        "5. Interval": "5min",
        "6. Output Size": "Full size",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    },
    "Time Series FX (5min)": {
        "2020-12-25 08:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2187",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 08:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 08:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2192",
            "2. high": "1.2192",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2192",
            "2. high": "1.2193",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2194",
            "2. high": "1.2194",
            "3. low": "1.2194",
            "4. close": "1.2194"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2192",
            "2. high": "1.2194",
            "3. low": "1.2192",
            "4. close": "1.2194"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2194",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2192"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2192",
            "2. high": "1.2192",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2195",
            "2. high": "1.2195",
            "3. low": "1.2195",
            "4. close": "1.2195"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2195",
            "2. high": "1.2195",
            "3. low": "1.2195",
            "4. close": "1.2195"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2192",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2195"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2195",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2194"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2197",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2193"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 07:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2201",
            "2. high": "1.2203",
            "3. low": "1.2200",
            "4. close": "1.2200"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2196",
            "2. high": "1.2197",
            "3. low": "1.2193",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2194",
            "4. close": "1.2195"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2196",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2197",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2198",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2200",
            "3. low": "1.2195",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2194",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2198",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2196"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2194",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2194",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2196",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2194",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2194",
            "2. high": "1.2197",
            "3. low": "1.2194",
            "4. close": "1.2195"
        },
        "2020-12-25 06:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2197",
            "3. low": "1.2193",
            "4. close": "1.2194"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2197",
            "3. low": "1.2195",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2193",
            "2. high": "1.2197",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2196"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2193",
            "2. high": "1.2193",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2193"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2193",
            "2. high": "1.2193",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2193"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2192",
            "4. close": "1.2193"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2200",
            "3. low": "1.2198",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2200",
            "2. high": "1.2201",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2201",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2201"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2198",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2198",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 05:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2195",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2195",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2196",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2196",
            "2. high": "1.2200",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2198",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2196"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2200",
            "2. high": "1.2200",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2201",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2197"
        },
        "2020-12-25 04:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2200",
            "2. high": "1.2201",
            "3. low": "1.2199",
            "4. close": "1.2200"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2198",
            "2. high": "1.2201",
            "3. low": "1.2198",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2196",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2199",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2193",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2198",
            "2. high": "1.2200",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2199"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2198",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2197",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2197",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2196",
            "2. high": "1.2198",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2199",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2198"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2193",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2190"
        },
        "2020-12-25 03:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2193",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2193"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2193",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2191",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2189"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2191",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2189"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2192",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2190",
            "2. high": "1.2190",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2192",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2190"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2192",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2190"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2192",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2192"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2189",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2190",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2190",
            "2. high": "1.2190",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 02:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2191",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2190"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2187",
            "2. high": "1.2190",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2189"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2188",
            "3. low": "1.2181",
            "4. close": "1.2186"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2187",
            "3. low": "1.2178",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2178",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2181"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2178",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2177",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2178",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2177",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2177",
            "4. close": "1.2179"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2175",
            "4. close": "1.2179"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2175",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2174",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 01:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2172",
            "2. high": "1.2176",
            "3. low": "1.2170",
            "4. close": "1.2175"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2170",
            "4. close": "1.2172"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2179",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2178",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2180",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2178",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2180",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2182",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2182",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-25 00:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2182",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2181",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2182",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2182",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2181",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2181",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2181",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2182"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2182"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 23:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2181"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2180",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2180",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2180",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2186",
            "3. low": "1.2179",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2186",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2186",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 22:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2185",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2186",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2186",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2185"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2185",
            "2. high": "1.2185",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2185",
            "3. low": "1.2181",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2185",
            "3. low": "1.2181",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2185",
            "3. low": "1.2181",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2181",
            "2. high": "1.2184",
            "3. low": "1.2181",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:20:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2184",
            "3. low": "1.2181",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:15:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2183",
            "3. low": "1.2181",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:10:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2184",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:05:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2183",
            "2. high": "1.2184",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        },
        "2020-12-24 21:00:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2184",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 20:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2185",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 20:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2185",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2185"
        },
        "2020-12-24 20:45:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2184",
            "2. high": "1.2186",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2184"
        },
        "2020-12-24 20:40:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2186",
            "2. high": "1.2186",
            "3. low": "1.2182",
            "4. close": "1.2185"
        },
        "2020-12-24 20:35:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2185",
            "2. high": "1.2186",
            "3. low": "1.2183",
            "4. close": "1.2185"
        },
        "2020-12-24 20:30:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2182",
            "2. high": "1.2185",
            "3. low": "1.2181",
            "4. close": "1.2185"
        },
        "2020-12-24 20:25:00": {
            "1. open": "1.2180",
            "2. high": "1.2184",
            "3. low": "1.2180",
            "4. close": "1.2183"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use a direct pandas function on it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict["Time Series FX (5min)"])
```

The output looks like below:

[image]

Comment: `DataFrame.from_dict()` has the parameter `orient` set to `'columns'` by default, so the timestamps will be the columns with your current code; you need to set `orient='index'`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html